# getcontext() in MyThreadYield(void) fetches null context

Tags: c, process, operating-system, pthreads

I am having an unusual problem and unable to find the reason causing it.

I'm developing user-level non-preemtive thread library.

```
void MyThreadYield(void) {
    if(myThreadLib.readyQ->size > 0) {
        ucontext_t currentContext;
        getcontext(&currentContext);
        myThreadLib.runningMyThread->ctx = currentContext;
        queueEnqueue(myThreadLib.readyQ, myThreadLib.runningMyThread);
        myThreadLib.runningMyThread = queueDequeue(myThreadLib.readyQ);
        setcontext(&(myThreadLib.runningMyThread->ctx));
    }
}
```

After `getcontext(&currentContext)` is executed, ss_stack in currentContext is NULL. Following is the snapshot of currentContext

[image]
And after `myThreadLib.runningMyThread->ctx = currentContext;` is executed it modifies the readyQ, don't know why.

However, `setcontext(&(myThreadLib.runningMyThread->ctx));` executes fine and the context is changed successfully, but gives Segfault when MyThreadYield() called again.

Can you please help me out with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Charlie, but here, after getcontext(&currentContext) is executed the uc_stack of currentContext is NULL. This is when I'm still in MyThreadYield() function. Moreover, I'm assigning currentContext to a MyThread structure which is dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In glib-2.17, I got the getcontext() assemble code:

```
0x0000000000401b50 <+0>:     mov    %rbx,0x80(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b57 <+7>:     mov    %rbp,0x78(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b5b <+11>:    mov    %r12,0x48(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b5f <+15>:    mov    %r13,0x50(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b63 <+19>:    mov    %r14,0x58(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b67 <+23>:    mov    %r15,0x60(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b6b <+27>:    mov    %rdi,0x68(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b6f <+31>:    mov    %rsi,0x70(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b73 <+35>:    mov    %rdx,0x88(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b7a <+42>:    mov    %rcx,0x98(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b81 <+49>:    mov    %r8,0x28(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b85 <+53>:    mov    %r9,0x30(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b89 <+57>:    mov    (%rsp),%rcx
0x0000000000401b8d <+61>:    mov    %rcx,0xa8(%rdi)
0x0000000000401b94 <+68>:    lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
0x0000000000401b99 <+73>:    mov    %rcx,0xa0(%rdi)
0x0000000000401ba0 <+80>:    lea    0x1a8(%rdi),%rcx
0x0000000000401ba7 <+87>:    mov    %rcx,0xe0(%rdi)
0x0000000000401bae <+94>:    fnstenv (%rcx)
0x0000000000401bb0 <+96>:    fldenv (%rcx)
0x0000000000401bb2 <+98>:    stmxcsr 0x1c0(%rdi)
0x0000000000401bb9 <+105>:   lea    0x128(%rdi),%rdx
0x0000000000401bc0 <+112>:   xor    %esi,%esi
0x0000000000401bc2 <+114>:   xor    %edi,%edi
0x0000000000401bc4 <+116>:   mov    $0x8,%r10d
0x0000000000401bca <+122>:   mov    $0xe,%eax
0x0000000000401bcf <+127>:   syscall
0x0000000000401bd1 <+129>:   cmp    $0xfffffffffffff001,%rax
0x0000000000401bd7 <+135>:   jae    0x410f70 <__syscall_error>
0x0000000000401bdd <+141>:   xor    %eax,%eax
0x0000000000401bdf <+143>:   retq
```

It seems that only the uc_mcontext is modified in the getcontext() call. 
The uc_stack is untouched.

By reading getcontext info, get following words:

The Unix standard provides one more set of functions to control the
execution path and these functions are more powerful than those
discussed in this chapter so far.  These function **were** part of the
original System V API and by this route were added to the Unix API.
Beside on branded Unix implementations these interfaces are not widely
available.  Not all platforms and/or architectures the GNU C Library is
available on provide this interface.  Use `configure' to detect the
availability.

And the man getcontext has the following words:

CONFORMING TO
       SUSv2, POSIX.1-2001.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of  getcontext(),
       citing  portability issues, and recommending that applications be rewritten to
       use POSIX threads instead.

So I think getcontext/setcontext/swapcontext/makecontext are all obselete and should be avoid used.