# use swapcontext() or getcontext() & setcontext() to write a yield() function for a thread library

Tags: c, multithreading

We need to implement a thread library. But I really cannot work this yield() function out...
So in yield(), we need to push the current thread to the end of the ready thread queue, and pop the first thread out and execute it.(FIFO) I am using the swapcontext(). So my code is like this.

```
yield()
{
 if(head!=NULL) // if FIFO is not empty, yield to a ready thread`
 {
    ready_queue_entry * old_thread= NULL;
    old_thread = new_thread;

    Push(old_thread);// push the current one to the FIFO
    new_thread = Pop();// pop the first one from the FIFO

    //save the current context and jump to the new thread context.
    swapcontext(&(old_thread->context),&(new_thread->context)); 
  }
}
```

I am sure my Pop and Push functions work well. But I cannot get the right thread context. I am really confused. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar problem. Please see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725166/getcontext-in-mythreadyieldvoid-fetches-null-context/18732754#18732754)

Try to use "sigsetjmp/siglongjmp" instead.

Comment: We are told to use these four context switch function...Really do not know how to debug now... :(

Comment: I made some experiments on those getcontext/swapcontext functions with no error. Can you paste the error info, othercase we have no clue to look what really go wrong. One clue is that you should first make some try to avoid use the automatic var in the called function. Because these automaic var are stored in the registers, the value in which can be changed unexpectly in swapcontext.

Comment: Thanks. This piece of code is actually right. I finally found out the problem was from the part that I initialize a context. Anyway, thank you.